# How to cope with Haskell name space?

Tags: json, haskell, jira, aeson

I'm writing a `data` record to marshall a `JIRA` `JSON` object. The problem is, multiple objects have the same labels for name/value pairs. For example :

(returned from curl and formatted)

```
{"expand":"schema,names"
,"startAt":0
,"maxResults":2
,"total":74
,"issues":[
           {"expand":"editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations"
           ,"id":"183614"
           ,"self":"https://10.64.16.44/rest/api/latest/issue/183614"
           ,"key":"BNAP-339"
           ,"fields":{"versions":[
                                  {"self":"https://10.64.16.44/rest/api/2/version/28240"  
                                  ,"id":"28240"
                                  ,"name":"2012-12-07"
                                  ,"archived":false
                                  ,"released":false
                                  }
                                 ]
                     ,"status":{"self":"https://10.64.16.44/rest/api/2/status/1"
                               ,"description":"The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it."
                               ,"iconUrl":"https://10.64.16.44/images/icons/status_open.gif"
                               ,"name":"Open"
                               ,"id":"1"
                               }
                     ,"description":"Do Re Mi Fa"
                     ,"resolution":null
                     }
           }
          ]
```

when I construct the problematic corresponding Haskell `data` records I get:

```
data Issue = Issue {expand :: String
                   ,id :: String
                   ,self :: String
                   ,key :: String
                   ,fields :: Fields
                   } deriving Generic


data Version = Version {self :: String
                       ,id :: String
                       ,name :: String
                       ,archived :: Bool
                       ,released :: Bool
                       } deriving Generic
```

and 'id' and 'self' will clash. It occured to me I could solve this by just changing the names in the records and fixing it with a manually-created `FromJSON` instance.
Any alternative solutions would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solve this in protocol buffers by putting things like `Issue` and `Version` in separate files in the same hierarchy.

Haskell only uses separate modules to control namespaces, so this is the orthodox solution.

Much much fancier: use type classes to define available name:

```
class Has'self a b | a -> bwhere
   get'self :: a -> b
   set'self :: b -> a -> b

instance Has'self Issue String where ...
instance Has'self Version String where ....
```

EDIT: The comments below remind me to give more verbose advice.  Do not use Has'self like solutions -- those that have gone that road report it gets ugly.  I can vouch for the path of separate modules.

PS: Perhaps you can use the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library for your fields!

Comment: Note that `HasFoobar` style typeclasses are almost always a terrible idea when it comes to writing clean, well-structured Haskell code. But when trying to match the structure of non-Haskell code for interop purposes, if the other side relies heavily on overloaded functions and/or subtype hierarchies, there may not be any better approach.

Comment: I'm upvoting the part where you recommended separate files.  Type classes make for a poor namespacing solution since they are very difficult for users to reason about the types and will silently fail and do the wrong thing when applied to the wrong type.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative that should work is to use a single data type that contains the distinct records.  For example, the following data type is capable of representing your value without field conflicts:

```
import Prelude hiding (id)

data JIRA = JIRA
  { expand :: String
  , startAt :: Int
  , maxResults :: Int
  , total :: Int
  , issues :: [JIRA]
  } | Issue 
  { expand :: String
  , id :: Int
  , self :: String
  , key :: String
  , fields :: JIRA
  } | Field
  { versions :: [JIRA]
  , status :: JIRA
  , description :: String
  , resolution :: Maybe String
  } | Version
  { self :: String
  , id :: Int
  , name :: String
  , archived :: Bool
  , released :: Bool
  } | Status
  { self :: String
  , description :: String
  , iconUrl :: String
  , name :: String
  , id :: Int
  }


yourExample = JIRA
  { expand = "schema, names"
  , startAt = 0
  , maxResults = 2
  , total = 74
  , issues = [ Issue
               { expand = "editmeta, etc..."
               , id = 12345
               , self = "https://xyz"
               , key = "BLAH"
               , fields = Field
                          { versions = [ Version
                                          { self = "https://foobar"
                                          , id = 1234
                                          , name = "quux"
                                          , archived = False
                                          , released = False
                                          }
                                       ]
                          , status = Status
                                     { self = "https://etc"
                                     , description = "issue"
                                     , iconUrl = "https://iconurl"
                                     , name = "open"
                                     , id = 1
                                     }
                          , description = "another description"
                          , resolution = Nothing
                          }
                 }
               ]
  }
```

Comment: Note that the above only works if all `id` are the same type (`Int`) and all `self` are the same type (`String`), etc.